# Why Ajaxcontroltoolkit is creating folders like ar,cs,de

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit

In have my application configured in asp.net.

I am using ajaxcontroltoolkit. After building the application, it creates lot of folders like  ar,cs,de etc.... and it contains ajaxcontroltoolkit.dlls,

I don't know why it creates this many dlls.

Can anyone please help me to get out of this?

Comment: Those sound like country codes - perhaps string localization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those directories are for language-specific controls.
(de = Deutsch etc.)

You can delete them, but I'm not sure how it will affect users using language-specific encoding.